# Python error when searching sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/michael/Dropbox/lagniappe/database.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = raw_input('Search for a title:')

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nerd WHERE title LIKE '%?%';", query)

print cursor.fetchall()
```

Retuns the error:

```
michael@piplup:~$ python sqlite.py 
Search for a title:test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlite.py", line 10, in <module>
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nerd WHERE title LIKE '%?%';", query)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 4 supplied.
```

All I want it to do is to print out the data it receives from the database to the console. Eventually I would like to manipulate this data, but I just need the query to work right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, the parameter is supposed to be a sequence - Python is interpreting it as a list of four characters, rather than a four-character string.

Secondly, the placeholder has to be the entire element, and not in quotes. You'll need to add the percent characters yourself:

```
query = raw_input('Search for a title:')
query = '%' + query + '%'
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nerd WHERE title LIKE ?", (query,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a tuple to `cursor.execute`. Try `(query,)` instead of `query`.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nerd WHERE title LIKE '%?%';", (query,))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the second parameter of the `execute` method is supposed to be a sequence, and you are passing a string (which is interpreted as a sequence of characters), that's why it says `... and there are 4 supplied.`

Second, the quotes around the argument of your `LIKE` comparison prevent the execute method to interpret the `?` as a placeholder; instead it's being interpreted as the literal `?`.

So, for your query to work correctly, you have to do two things:

1. Add the `%` to your the `query` argument, insted of embedd them into the SQL query.
2. Pass the `query` argument inside a sequence (a one-element tuple or list).

Here's how your script would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/michael/Dropbox/lagniappe/database.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = '%%%s%%' % raw_input('Search for a title:') # puts the input between %
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nerd WHERE title LIKE ?;", (query,)) # passes the query as a tuple
print cursor.fetchall()
```